# Conditional Compilation Symbols not working

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, conditional-compilation, asp.net-core-3.1

There are plenty of reported bugs in almost every version of Visual Studio with similar or exactly the same issue. The problem is that every bug report I found has been already resolved. Additional info: My exact same code has worked a month ago. I am using .NET Core 3.1.100 and Visual Studio 16.4.2.

**Project GUI**

[image: Conditional Compilation Symbol Project GUI]

**.csproj Configuration**

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Demo|AnyCPU'">
  <DefineConstants>DEMO</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Code** (as you can see, the `DEMO` symbol will not be applied).

[image: Conditional Compilation Symbol usage]

Has anyone an idea how to hotfix this issue for my production environment?

Thanks  in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how this should be done in ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET Core doesn't use the concept of build configurations natively, and while you can sort of use them in places like this or compiler directives, it goes against the grain of ASP.NET Core app design. ASP.NET Core apps are build once, deploy anywhere, in contrast to ASP.NET where you needed to build for each environment separately.

Instead, this should be handled via config and environments. You can even have a "Demo" environment, if you like, which would then allow you to just inject `IWebHostingEnvironment` and check `_env.IsEnvironment("Demo")`. Short of that, you should simply specify via config (JSON, environment variable, etc.) a "Demo" boolean, and then pull that out of `IConfiguration`.

Comment: Seams very reasonable. Is there any documentation which mentions the obsolescence of the build configurations in .NET Core?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you very much, sir! You saved me some headache :)